# Re-using access token in Firebase 3

Tags: ios, swift, firefox, firebase-authentication

I have an iOS app that uses Firebase as a backend for authentication.

Once a user logs in and then closes the app, I don't want the user to have to re-enter their email and password. My approach is to save the access token after a successful login to the Keychain, and then when the user comes back to the app, use the token from the keychain to signin.

I've tried using the method `FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCustomToken(customToken) { (user, error) in` but that's not quite right as that's for when using custom tokens, which is not what I'm doing.

Is there a way for me to do this?

```
// login with email / password
FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(email, password: password, completion: { (firebaseUser, error) in
  if error == nil {
      FIRAuth.auth()!.currentUser!.getTokenWithCompletion({ (token, error) in
        if error == nil {
          // save token to keychain
        } else {
          print(error)
        }
      })

  } else {
    print(error)
  }
})


// user comes back to app
do {
// get saved token from keychain 
  if let myToken = try keychain.get("token") {
    FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithCustomToken(myToken, completion: { (user: FIRUser?, error: NSError?) in
      if error == nil {
        // show post login screen
      } else {

      }
    })
  }
} catch {
// error getting token from keychain
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I was approaching this problem in the wrong way. Saving a token is appropriate when using a 3rd party authentication provider, like Facebook, Google, etc and getting an OAuth token in return from one of those services.

In my case when logging in using email and password, a token is not required and instead the password can be securely saved in the Keychain and used later for login.